# Maximum likelihood for two dependent variables

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Suppose you have a box containing 10 balls, of which $\theta$ are white and the rest are green. Suppose we take two balls for without replacement and let $X_i = 1$ if the i-th drawn ball is white and $0$ otherwise. Find the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$

I was wondering how to solve this problem, if there were replacements in question I could do it easily, since then the $X_i$ would be independent. But in this case I'm not sure how to proceed, I even thought of considering the sum of both outcomes,  but didn't come to any solution as well

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
P(X_1=1, X_2=1) &= \frac{\theta}{10} \cdot \frac{\theta-1}{9}
\\
P(X_1=1, X_2=0) &= \frac{\theta}{10} \cdot \frac{10-\theta}{9}
\\
P(X_1=0, X_2=1) &= \frac{10-\theta}{10} \cdot \frac{\theta}{9}
\\
P(X_1=0, X_2=0) &= \frac{10-\theta}{10} \cdot \frac{9-\theta}{9}
\end{align}

This can be written in one expression as
$$P(X_1=x_1, X_2 =x_2)
= \frac{1}{90}
[\theta(\theta-1)]^{x_1 x_2}
[\theta(10-\theta)]^{x_1 (1-x_2)}
[(10-\theta)\theta]^{(1-x_1)x_2}
[(10-\theta)(9-\theta)]^{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)}.
$$
I think you can then take the logarithm of this likelihood and then optimize for $\theta$.